# Why functions prototype is chained repeatedly?

Tags: javascript

I'm very new to JavaScript. I'm reading from JavaScript good parts. It says :

> Every function object is also created with a **prototype** property

So I did something like this :

```
function test() {
}

console.log(test.prototype);
```

Using Chrome's developer tools, I find the output as follows :

[image]

I'm really confused with this output. Why does `constructor`'s `prototype` property again nested with `constructor`? And why does this goes on like a *chain*? Where I'm missing the concept?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The `prototype` property of a function holds the object from which all instances of that function will inherit when created with the `new` operator. And all these prototype objects (usually) have a `constructor` property which points back to the function - there you have the circular reference. So, as a `new test()` inherits that property, `(new test).constructor === test` evaluates to `true`.

You will need to distinguish between the `prototype` property of a function object and the prototype object from which an object inherits - often referenced as "the internal `[[prototype]]` property".

A constructor is a function, not to say a `Function`, and has both. Therefore it inherits from the `Function.prototype` object - where the `constructor` property says that all functions are constructed by the `Function` constructor. If your developers console would show the prototype of `Function` objects, you could see them. I think there is an option in the settings.

So, the famous "prototype chain" is not about the `constructor` and/or `prototype` properties, but about the prototype object from which that object inherits from:

```
 function test() {}              new test()
   (a Function)              (a test instance)
        ||                           ||
        ||                           ||
        \/                           \/
 Function.prototype            test.prototype
(a Function, by spec)           (an Object)
        ||                           ||
        ||                           ||
        \/                           \/
 Object.prototype             Object.prototype
        ||                           ||
        ||                           ||
        \/                           \/
       null                         null
```

Comment: Thanks for the link, I already wondered about the output when fast-checking `Object.getPrototypeOf(test)` in the console...

Comment: Nice answer.. Many things to take from your answer :)

Comment: @Bergi- Please explain  - "A constructor is a function, not to say a Function, and has both. Therefore it inherits from the Function.prototype object"

Comment: @jason: A "constructor function" is both a) a constructor that has a `.prototype` property and b) an object - more specifically a `Function` instance - that inherits properties from its prototype.

Answer (score 1):

Thats one of the very good books to pick up.

It covers more of javascript from programmers point of view covering all the object oriented techniques and most of the things in it aren't covered in any other books on javascript.

And about prototype.
Every object in JavaScript holds a hidden piece of state – a reference to another object known as the object’s prototype. 
Prototype objects in JavaScript give us inheritance, and they allow us to share method implementations, too. Prototypes also chain. In other words, since a prototype object is just an object, then a prototype object can maintain a reference to another prototype object.

Prototype in Javascript is little complicated part as I have experienced while learning it.

This is a great [reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ff852808.aspx) to know how prototype in js works.