# It is said that all Javascript objects have a prototype property, but I only see foo.prototype if foo is a function?

Tags: javascript, prototype

It is often said that every Javascript object has a `prototype` property, but I find that `foo.prototype` has a value only if `foo` is a function.

On Chrome and Firefox, `obj.__proto__` has a value -- is this the said `prototype` property?  But on IE 9,  it won't work (is there some way that can?), and I thought by `prototype` property, that means `obj.prototype` should work?

I understand that `Object.getPrototypeOf(obj)` seems to show this `prototype` property, but why need a special method to get it?  Why not just like `person.name`, which is to get the `name` property of the `person` object?

---

**Update:** by the way, `obj.constructor.prototype` seems to **sometimes** be that prototype, but sometimes not, as in the following code done with Prototypal inheritance with no constructor: (this method is in the Pro Javascript Design Patterns book by Harmes and Diaz by Apress 2008, p. 46)

```
var Person = {
    name: 'default value',
    getName: function() {
        return this.name;
    }
}

var reader = clone(Person);
console.log(reader.getName());
reader.name = "Ang Lee";
console.log(reader.getName());

function clone(obj) {
    function F() {};
    F.prototype = obj;
    return new F;
}

console.log("the prototype of reader is", Object.getPrototypeOf(reader));

console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(reader) === reader.constructor.prototype);
console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(reader) == reader.constructor.prototype);

console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(reader) === reader.__proto__);
console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(reader) == reader.__proto__);
```

the result will show false, false, true, true for the last 4 lines.

Comment: Objects are all related to a prototype, but not necessarily by a visible property. In other words, the JavaScript runtime internals know what the prototype object is, but it may not be possible for your code to determine what it is. As to *why* that is true, well, it's just the way that JavaScript was implemented.

Comment: Anyone who says "every JavaScript object has a prototype property" is referring to the internal property (exposed as `__proto__` on most browsers, as you mentioned).

Comment: Take a look at this similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9451881/

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Every JavaScript object has an internal "prototype" property, often called [[prototype]], which points to the object from which it directly inherits. This is exposed in FF and Chrome by the non-standard `__proto__` property. `Object.getPrototypeOf` is a getter for this internal property.

Every JavaScript function [object] has a property `prototype`, which is initialized with an [nearly] empty object. When you create a new instance of this function by calling it as a constructor, the [[prototype]] of that new object will point to the constructor's `prototype` object.

If you get the [[prototype]] of a function (every function is an object, so it has one), it will result in the `Function.prototype` object from which functions inherit their methods (like bind, call, apply etc). See also [Why functions prototype is chained repeatedly?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10812392/1048572) on that.

Comment: you mean with "nearly" empty object?  how come you put in square bracket?

Comment: The nearly empty object has a non-enumerable property `constructor` on it, which points to the constructor function. The notation with the double square-brackets comes from the [official EcmaScript specification](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-8.6.2) which uses this format for all internal properties.

Comment: what about the "single" bracket notation such as yours? [nearly] empty

Comment: That's just my personal style of [parenthesis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parenthesis) - I often use square brackets for [single] words when omitting them does not change the meaning of the sentences, but could help understanding or is technically [more] correct. Not sure about official grammar rules regarding that, I'm no native English writer :-)

Comment: @Bergi isn't there a `__proto__` property as well, in addition to the `constructor` property ? Also, this means that there is another internal `[[prototype]]` too.

Comment: @Taurus No, there is no `__proto__`, that's just a deprecated inherited getter/setter. Of course, every prototype object does have a [[prototype]] from which it inherits.

Comment: But if there were no `__proto__` then when trying to access it, you would get `undefined`. This is definitely not the case, try to compare `x.prototype.__proto__` with `Object.prototype`, it will evaluate to true; this would definitely not be the case if it were not there.

Comment: @Taurus As I said, it's inherited. And it's deprecated, so don't spend much more thought on it. Use `Object.getPrototypeOf(x.prototype) == Object.prototype` instead

Comment: Doesn't an inherited property count as a property anyways ? i am just curious.

Comment: @Taurus Since we were discussing prototypes anyway, I had interpreted it to mean "own property".

Comment: @Bergi Thanks. Now that we've come this far anyways, could i ask you a small question ? Why is `Object.prototype.__proto__` null ? Shouldn't it be equal to `Object.prototype` since `Object.prototype` is basically an instance of Object (created with an object literal), so its `__proto__` property should just be a reference to the prototype of the object it was created from, which is `Object` ? I am wrong but naturally i would expect `Object.prototype.__proto__ === Object.prototype` to evaluate to true.

Comment: @Taurus No, a prototype is not "created from" its respective constructor, rather it is what *defines* an instance. And [[prototype]] chains must be linear, no circles or self-references are allowed - imagine what it would mean for the lookup mechanism.

Comment: @bergi i am not saying a prototype is created from its constructor, i was saying that its __proto__ should link to the prototype of the constructor function the instance has been created from ? Is this statement incorrect? Sorry man but it is a bit hard explaining this in a comment.

Comment: @Taurus Yes, but I'm saying that prototype objects are not *instances* at all. They are supposed to link their parent prototype, not themselves.

Comment: By prototype, do you mean like `Object.prototype` ? If so, aren't those literally created with an object literal by JS automatically, and therefore, instances of `Object'. What i am saying is: isn't `Object.prototype` an instance of `Object` ?

Comment: @Taurus I'm talking of all prototype objects, `x.prototype` and `Object.prototype` and every other one. No, they are created automatically, but not through an object literal. And see for yourself: `Object.prototype instanceof Object` or `x.prototype instanceof x` are both false (because `x.prototype.isPrototypeOf(x.prototype)` is as well, given that it inherits from `Object.prototype` *not from itself* - and `Object.prototype` doesn't inherit from itself neither, it inherits from nothing: `null`).

Comment: @Bergi oh thanks! That is what i was talking about. So prototype objects aren't created using an object literal and Javascript does some behind-the-scenes magic to determine the `__proto__` of prototype objects.

Comment: There are some special functions in JS which lack a `.prototype` property, I don't really remember which ones they were and neither MDN nor Google is helping, so I must resort to you again, which functions are those ?

Comment: @Taurus Arrow functions, methods (of `class`es or as shorthands in object literals), and bound functions.

Comment: @Bergi Thanks :)

Answer (score 6):

It is the `constructor` of every Object that has a `prototype`. So for some `foo`, `bar`or `foobar`:

```
var foo = {};
console.log(foo.constructor.prototype); //=> Object
var bar = 5;
console.log(bar.constructor.prototype); //=> Number
function Foobar(){} 
var foobar = new Foobar; //Foobar used a constructor
console.log(foobar.constructor.prototype); //=> Foobar
```

Comment: aha, sometimes the constructor way won't work it seems, please see the update in the question

Comment: @動靜能量 That's why you see people manually updating the constructor when they do prototypal inheritance... something like `(F.prototype = obj).constructor = F;`