# Javascript: need explanation for the output of console.log(new function(){return this})

Tags: javascript

The following code:

```
console.log(new function(){return this})
```

is giving the following output:

[image: output in chrome console]

Ref to the img, Please explain the output (why does such infinite repeating depth exists?).

note: I'm a newbie in javascript and was trying various code and found this behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In JavaScript function is object and has all properties which belong to objects. So all of them you see in your console line.

Short description:

`name :''` - anonymous function in your case name of function is empty

`caller:null` function that call your function

`arguments: null` all arguments which were passed into function

You need take a look at Inheritance of JS

http://phrogz.net/JS/classes/OOPinJS2.html

Comment: but why is that infinite repetition inside the prototype Object?

Comment: see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10812254/why-functions-prototype-is-chained-repeatedly

Answer (score 0):

1. An Object's `.constructor` property will usually reference a Function,
2. Functions are objects, which inherit from a prototype object.
3. The prototype object from which functions inherit has a `.constructor` property.
4. Go to step 1