# how to explain " Function.__proto__ === Function.prototype"?

Tags: javascript, prototype, chain

I'm learning Javascript recently.

When I read the chapter about "prototype chain", I still think I can master it.

[prototype pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GeKR7.jpg)

But when I saw this picture, I was really confused.

How should I understand the

`Function.__proto__ === Function.prototype`

?

There is a saying "In javascript almost everything is inherited from Object except primitive types."

I usually think function is used to "construct" an instance while object is already an instance, so how could they be equal?

Comment: `Function` is a function. A function's prototype is `Function.prototype`.

Comment: in JS every `function` is actually a `Function Object`  The real difficulty lies within the ambiguity of `objects`. They can be instances and constructors

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21319594/javascript-function-prototype-object-function-or-both